# Video html5: how to get currently played source

Tags: jquery, html, video, html5-video, mediaelement

in a `<video>` tag, how can I know the currently played source URL with JQuery if there are many sources (different codec)?

I tried with the src property, but it's empty.

Thanks!

Pv

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The latest version of the HTML5 spec gives the [currentSrc](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/complete/video.html#dom-media-currentsrc) property for this purpose. I'm not sure if all browsers support this.